# How to use timeout for requests.get in python when using Multi threading and progress bar?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, tqdm

I am doing a Threading with a progress bar with tqdm for requests at the same time 30 URLs using requests.get. The URLs are attributes of many objects stored in a list.

```
with Pool(30) as my_pool:
    server_response = \
        list(tqdm.tqdm(
              my_pool.imap(
                  requests.get,
                  [my_object.url for my_object in list_of_objects]),
                    total=len(list_urls)))
```

How can I use the argument `timeout=10` for the function `requests.get()` in that snipped?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to rewrite the code.

```
import os
import traceback
import tqdm
import multiprocessing as mp

def main():
    urls = [my_object.url for my_object in list_of_objects]
    pool = mp.Pool(30)
    for result in tqdm.tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(process_url, urls)):
        if isinstance(result, Exception):
            print("Got exception: {}".format(result))
        else:
            print("Got OK result: {}".format(result))


def process_url(url):
    try:
        return requests.get(url, timeout=10)
    except Exception as ex:
        return Exception("Err on url {}".format(url)
                         + os.linesep + traceback.format_exc())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I  am getting this error. Could you please explaing me what is this about?

  File ".../lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)


AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'newa_threading.<locals>.process_url'